# Android - 3 column row layout - how do I make it take up a percentage of screen?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have this layout with hard-coded widths:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:paddingTop="4dip"
     android:paddingBottom="6dip"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:textSize="13sp"
     android:weightSum="1.0">

     <TextView android:id="@+id/TRAIN_CELL"
         android:layout_width="0dp"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_weight=".60"/>




      <TextView android:id="@+id/FROM_CELL"
         android:layout_width="0dp"
         android:textSize="20sp"
         android:textStyle="bold"
         android:gravity="center"
         android:textColor="@color/light_best_blue"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
         android:layout_weight=".20"/>


     <TextView android:id="@+id/TO_CELL"
         android:layout_width="0dp"
         android:textSize="20sp"
         android:textStyle="bold" 
         android:gravity="center"
         android:layout_weight=".20"
         android:textColor="@color/light_best_blue"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"  />

</LinearLayout>
```

But is there a way to give each column a percentage of the width?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
layout_width="0dp"
layout_weight="x"
```

where `x` is your percentage on each element. See http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/linear.html

Comment: I tried some different things which didn't quite work. I posted my latest layout in my original question.  Would you be able to notice anything that might be not right there? Thanks!

Comment: nothing seems off. maybe use 0.20 instead of .20, or even use integers (60, 20, 20)

Answer (score 2):

You the weight attribute and the width as 0dp and specify the weightSum in the parent.

In your case set the android:weightSum of the linear layout to say 1 and divide that weight among the children say 0.3, 0.3 and 0.4. (android:layout_weight="0.3").

EDIT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:paddingTop="4dip"
 android:paddingBottom="6dip"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:textSize="13sp"
 android:weightSum="1.0"
 android:orientation="horizontal">

 <TextView android:id="@+id/TRAIN_CELL"
     android:layout_width="0dp"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_weight=".60"/>




  <TextView android:id="@+id/FROM_CELL"
     android:layout_width="0dp"
     android:textSize="20sp"
     android:textStyle="bold"
     android:gravity="center"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
     android:layout_weight=".20"/>


 <TextView android:id="@+id/TO_CELL"
     android:layout_width="0dp"
     android:textSize="20sp"
     android:textStyle="bold" 
     android:gravity="center"
     android:layout_weight=".20"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"  />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: that didn't quite work.  I updated my question with my new layout, and now the left side takes 90% of the screen, and nothing is left for the other two columns.

Comment: set the orientation of the parent linear layout to horizontal.

Comment: you mean of the outer layout which is the layout of the overall screen? Or the list layout which I have pasted here?

Comment: I added android:orientation="horizontal" to the linear layout snippet of the code I have in my answer, but that didn't do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

This post is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29861418/android-measure-screen-in-percentage/29865460#29865460) post.
Your can create every column width to required width in percentage
Check this [Android Measure Screen in percentage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29861418/android-measure-screen-in-percentage/29865460#29865460)