# Android Measure Screen in percentage

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I did so many research on Android layouts i found so many answers but not found any answer which tells me how can i measure screen in actual percentage
just found table layouts linear with weight, best one was linear with weight but difficult to manage percentage again!!!

Comment: "measure screen in actual percentage" ? no wonder you found nothing, you can measure the screen in pixels not percentage

Comment: measure what? Height? or Width?

Comment: you cant set percentage each view's in layout xml without Linearlayout. but you can in java class.

Comment: i have to measure width @ David

Comment: how can i do this in java ? @이남웅

Comment: with LayoutParam. and calculate device screen wide to percentage.
`DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
  context.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
  int deviceWidth = displayMetrics.widthPixels;
  int deviceHeight = displayMetrics.heightPixels;
  this.width  = deviceWidth;
  this.height = deviceHeight;`
and setLayoutParams with calculate width and height.

Answer (score 2):

**Percentage** means ratio out  of 100

Linear layout with weight is not difficult to manage you can technically manage linear layout in percentage like this,

Let suppose your main layout android:weightSum=”100”
that mean your total screen size is 100% now you can specify every layouts width

**Example**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="100" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/one"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="12"
            android:background="#FF9933"
            android:text="No:" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/two"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="63"
            android:background="#CC33CC"
            android:text="Desc" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/three"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="25"
            android:background="#FF9999"
            android:text="Total" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

according to percentage first column is 12% second is 63% and last one is 25%